# Adobe CQ5.5-How to display Page Thumbnail using API

Tags: aem

I have configured image for my page using sidekick >Page properties>Images tab. Now I want to fetch my this page image(thumbnail) in one of my jsp. Can someone give me pointers or code snippet for api class and method that I  can use to achieve this.

Thanks,
Rajeev

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the default image component as an example - /libs/foundation/components/image.

If you're putting your code into a component for your specific page type though, your code should be something like this:

```
if (currentNode.hasNode("image")) {
    String imagePath = currentNode.getNode("image").getPath();
    Resource imageRes = resourceResolver.getResource(imagePath);
    image = new Image(imageRes);

    image.loadStyleData(currentStyle);
    image.setSelector(".img");

    if (!currentDesign.equals(resourceDesign)) {
        image.setSuffix(currentDesign.getId());
    }
    image.draw(out);
}
```

Keep in mind though, even though you set an image, it does NOT mean it will show up - if you're using the default page dialog for page properties, it will only show a broken image.  That's because there is a bug in CQ where the sling:resourceType property of the image doesn't get set, and thus it won't show up.  This is because the .img selector that gets put on the image doesn't know what to do, unless it get's pointed to a resource type with a definition for the .img selector, so it can properly render the image.

I've uploaded a package that you can use as a hotfix for the issue with the default /libs/foundation/components/page component dialog, so that it will actually set the resource type when you upload an image.  You can find/download the package from my [Google Drive](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4HE1y0v3uzAcWVfMGFhT1gyUG8/edit?usp=sharing)

Hopefully that helps.  Let me know if you need more help.

**EDIT**

If you're trying to get the page properties image from one page on another page, you just need to use a resource resolver.  You should have one available to you in CQ, so this would essentially be the code:

```
Resource imageRes = resourceResolver.getResource(pathFromYourDialog);
Image image = new Image(imageRes);
```

The rest would be the same - you're just giving it a different path to start from.

Comment: Thanks Nicol for response. Here you are using currentNode which means it will take image from currentpage node. But in my component, i want to take thumbnail image of the page that I am taking from user using path field in dialog.

Comment: Do you mean that you are making a custom component that will take the image from the page properties of any page path that you give it?  If that's the case, you would still do the same thing as above, but you would just need to use the resource resolver.  I edited my example above to show you.

Comment: Since the "image" node is relative to the page, you want to use `currentPage.getContentResource().getResource("image")` to generically get to the image in components on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think Nicholaus was more on point with his EDIT answer to your immediate need. If the user is providing you a path to the thumbnail via the dialog (i.e. a DAM image).

You can simply create the image, or if it has DAM information you can load it as a DAM Asset and pull the necessary information.

```
Image image = new Image();
Resource imageResource = resourceResolver.getResource(imageUrl);
Asset imageAsset = imageResource.adaptTo(Asset.class);

Map<String, Object> valueMap = imageAsset.getMetadata();

long width = Long.parseLong(valueMap.get("tiff:ImageWidth").toString());
long height = Long.parseLong(valueMap.get("tiff:ImageLength").toString());
Object titleObject = valueMap.get("tiff:ImageTitle");
String title = (titleObject == null) ? null : titleObject.toString();

if (title != null)
{
  image.setTitle(title);
}

image.setWidth(width);
image.setHeight(height);
image.setUrl(imageUrl);
```

This is a little long hand for what Nicholaus had suggested, the Image class will create itself based off the Resource you pass it. (actually upvoted Nicholaus for that, have some optimizations we can make).

Another, simpler option would be to just use the src that the user passes through, in the event that all you're doing is setting a thumbnail. I'm guessing you could be safe in doing something like:

in java:

```
String thumbSrc = properties.get("thumbSrc", "defaultThumbnail.path");
if (!thumbSrc.isEmpty())
{
  pageContext("thumbSrc", thumbSrc);
}
```

in jsp:

```
<img alt="thumbnail" src="${thumbSrc}"/>
```

or if you don't want to do anything in the java you could just do something like

```
<c:if test="${not empty properties.thumbSrc}">
  <img alt="thumbnail" src="${properties.thumbSrc}"/>
</c:if>
```

In order to get the same result as the first part in just jsp, you'd need to wrap it in a choose, because passing it through some processing before sending to view makes it easier to set default values.