# CQ5 How do I render an image by InputStream from jcr:data?

Tags: aem

I saved my image using the *foundation/components/image* component, but I can not get the image again.

My JSP Code:

```
String src = "";

if(image.hasProperty("fileReference")){
    src = image.getProperty("fileReference").getString();

}else if(image.hasNode("file")){
    Node jcrContent = image.getNode("file").getNode("jcr:content");

    InputStream iContent = jcrContent.getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary().getStream();

    out.print(iContent);

    jcrContent.getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary().dispose();
}

 <img src="<%= src %>">
```

And my **image** is a Node.

Comment: I solved this problem with the follow code:
`if(imageNews.hasNode("file")){
Node jcrContent = imageNews;
String imagePath = jcrContent.getPath();
Resource imageRes = resourceResolver.getResource(imagePath);

Image image = new Image(imageRes);
image.loadStyleData(currentStyle);
image.setSelector(".img");                
if (!currentDesign.equals(resourceDesign)) {
 image.setSuffix(currentDesign.getId());
}                

image.draw(out);
}`

based in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16074449/adobe-cq5-5-how-to-display-page-thumbnail-using-api

Comment: I think you should move this comment to an answer and accept it :D